# Support most audio formats with MediaElement

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mediaelement.js

I stream online radios and my player needs to support most audio formats, in particular mp3, m3u8 and aac. My constraint is that I can't determine the provided audio type in advance.

It seems like MediaElement can handle all of these type individually if I provide the type. Is there a way to provide the url and then MediaElement will determine the appropriate audio type for the source, dynamically?

My html code

```
<div class="radio-container">
    <video id="radio-player"></video>
</div>
```

My javascript code

```
var url = 'http://stream.rncmedia.ca/choi.mp3'; //it is hard-coded for the example
var video = document.getElementById('radio-player');
video.src = url;

var player = new MediaElement(video, {
    success: function (media, node, player) {
        //play
    },
    error: function(e) {
        //error
    }
});
```

Furthermore, is there a player that can handle all of these audio format on web and mobile? When the MediaElement player fallback to a flash player, it is not available on mobile.

I would like to have some hints on how to achieve this.

Comment: i doubt the player handles any formats, that's up to the browser to support (or not), except in flash, which is not that helpful...